# How to Initialise and Then Append to an Empty 2D List?

Tags: python, list

Just a short logic puzzle : I'm trying to implement 4 master counters. In each master counter there exists sub-counters. I've done this by creating a 2D list.

So when the trigger is collected, it appends a sub-counter into each master counter and allows it to start counting. For example in the 4th master counter, there can be no more than 4 sub-counters and each  sub-counter can only exist for 240 cycles (hence the window condition). In the second master counter, there can only be 2 sub-counters and each counter can only count for 25 clock cycles

So far I have this:

```
def l1a(self):
    for x in xrange(len(self.counter)) :    
        self.counter[x].append([0])
        "Triggered"
    print self.counter

def counterReset(self):
    for j in xrange(len(self.counter)):
        print self.counter
        for k in xrange(len(self.counter[j])):
            print self.counter[j][k]
            if ((self.counter[j][k]) / self.window[j]) == 1:
                self.counter[j].pop(k) #delete counter
                print self.counter
    #print self.counter

def triggerRules(self):
    breakMe = False
    while breakMe == False:
        for i in xrange(len(self.counter)):
            if len(self.counter[i]) > i:
                breakMe = True
        break

    if breakMe == False:
        self.l1a()


def triggerClk(self):
    for i in xrange(len(self.counter)):
        for j in xrange(len(self.counter[i])):
            self.counter[i][j] += 1

def myClk(self):
    self.counterReset()

    self.clk += 1 
    self.triggerClk()

    nRand = random.randrange(0, self.max_word)


    if nRand < self.frequency :
        #print "Trying trigger"
        self.triggerRules()
```

But it just gives me an output of:

```
[[[0]], [[0]], [[0]], [[0]]]
[[[0]], [[0]], [[0]], [[0]]]
[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mp7trigsim.py", line 49, in <module>
    if __name__ == '__main__':main()
  File "mp7trigsim.py", line 27, in main
    trig = TriggerGen(i, max_word, clkCycles)
  File "TriggerGen.py", line 23, in __init__
    self.myClk()
  File "TriggerGen.py", line 60, in myClk
    self.counterReset()
  File "TriggerGen.py", line 37, in counterReset
    if ((self.counter[j][k]) / self.window[j]) == 1:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'
```

How do I get it so it just initialises the 4 master counters and then lets me append and pop them?

I was thinking I needed to start with:

```
[[0], [0], [0], [0]]
```

and eventually imagine if all the counters were ticking:

```
[[0,1], [1,12,1,13], [11,24,5,2], [22,43,24,56]]
```

I'm sure it's something subtle I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see that the statement just prior to the TypeError prints a list - that is why you are getting the error, list / int. And your diagnostic prints show that your nesting to three levels not two. In `l1a` try appending 0 instead of `[0]`.

Comment: Thanks, if you feel this was a well formatted question, please 1up